# comparion query in mysql not returning correct results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables with a difference of about 3000 records

```
select count(name) from t1
```

**returns 1847073**

```
select count(name) from t2
```

**returns 1813492**

but when I try to get the results that are in one that are not in the other I just get null results.

```
select t1.name from t1 where t1.name not in (select t2.name from t2);
```

I have also tried a left join with the table with more records on the left and it just runs forever

```
select t1.name from t1 left join t2 on t1.name = t2.name where t2.name is null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table `t1` could have some duplicated names, so it's perfectly fine that it has more records than table `t2` but still all of the names in `t1` are also present in `t2`.

But you should also consider the fact that some names might be NULL in table t1, and since `NULL NOT IN (....)` will be evaluated as NULL, they won't be shown unless you add an explicit condition:

```
OR t1.name IS NULL;
```

but to comply with the SQL standard, `IN`/`NOT IN` return `NULL` not only if the expression on the left hand side is NULL, but also if no match is found in the list and one of the expressions in the list is NULL, and you also need to exclude NULL names from the NOT IN subquery:

```
SELECT t1.name
FROM t1
WHERE
  t1.name NOT IN (SELECT t2.name FROM t2 WHERE t2.name IS NOT NULL)
  OR t1.name IS NULL;
```

Your second query looks fine, but you probably miss an index on name column, on both tables.

Comment: ok it seems thats on the right track, after i added that is null it gave 296 records that are null for name but have other data.. What do you think is the issue with the rest of the 2,000 something ? duplicates of this 296 null records ?

Comment: @EduardoDennis you are right, it's not just the NULL values in t1, also the subquery doesn't have to return null values, please see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
SELECT            t1.name
FROM              table1 t1
NATURAL LEFT JOIN table2 t2
WHERE             t2.name IS NULL
```